# HOW to port "compact" Python to "compact" Java?

Tags: java, python

A friend is doing an online Scala course and shared this.

```
# Write a recursive function that counts how many different ways you can make
# change for an amount, given a list of coin denominations. For example, there
# are 3 ways to give change for 4 if you have coins with denomiation 1 and 2:
# 1+1+1+1, 1+1+2, 2+2.
```

---

### If you are attending and still working on a solution, don't read this!

**(disclaimer: even if my Python solution may be wrong, I don't want to influence your thinking if you are on the course, one way or the other! I guess it is the *thinking* that goes into it that yields learning, not just the "solving"...)**

---

That aside...

I thought I'd have a go at it in Python as I don't have the Scala chops for it (I am not on the course myself, just interested in learning Python and Java and welcome "drills" to practice on).

Here's my solution, which I'd like to port to Java using as compact a notation as possible:

---

```
def show_change(money, coins, total, combo):
  if total == money:
    print combo, '=', money
    return 1
  if total > money or len(coins) == 0:
    return 0
  c = coins[0]
  return (show_change(money, coins, total + c, combo + [c]) +
    show_change(money, coins[1:], total, combo))

def make_change(money, coins):
  if money == 0 or len(coins) == 0:
    return 0
  return show_change(money, list(set(coins)), 0, [])

def main():
  print make_change(4, [2, 1])

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

---

### Question

- How compact can I make the above in Java, allowing the use of libraries external to the JDK if they help?

I tried doing the porting myself but it was getting *very* verbose and I thought the usual *"there must be a better way of doing this"*!

Here my attempt:

---

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import com.google.common.collect.Lists;
import com.google.common.primitives.Ints;
public class MakeChange {
  static int makeChange(int money, int[] coins) {
    if (money == 0 || coins.length == 0) {
      return 0;
    }
    return showChange(money, Ints.asList(coins), 0, new ArrayList<Integer>());
  }
  static int showChange(int money, List<Integer> coins, int total,
      List<Integer> combo) {
    if (total == money) {
      System.out.printf("%s = %d%n", combo, total);
      return 1;
    }
    if (total > money || coins.isEmpty()) {
      return 0;
    }
    int c = coins.get(0);
    List<Integer> comboWithC = Lists.newArrayList(combo);
    comboWithC.add(c);
    return (showChange(money, coins, total + c, comboWithC) + showChange(money,
        coins.subList(1, coins.size()), total, combo));
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(makeChange(4, new int[] { 1, 2 }));
  }
}
```

---

Specifically, what I dislike a lot is having to do the stuff below just to pass a copy of the list with an element appended to it:

```
    List<Integer> comboWithC = Lists.newArrayList(combo);
    comboWithC.add(c);
```

Please show me how compact and readable Java can be. I am still a beginner in both languages...

Comment: Some of what you've done to make this more compact in Python has made it less pythonic, and arguably less readable (e.g., `if …: return …` without a newline—and, worse, putting _two_ statements after the if, with a semicolon). Do you want to do the same kind of tricks in Java as well? You can take it even farther by removing all unnecessary whitespace, giving functions one-letter names, etc.

Comment: Java generally won't be compact

Comment: Good point! Absolutely not! So I am going to reinstate the whitespace! Gimme a minute.. done. Is it better now?

Comment: One more thing: This is tagged "functional-programming". But you're not doing anything particularly FP here; this whole thing almost works as K&R C… So, is it supposed to be in a more functional style, or is the tag wrong?

Comment: @abarnert: the tag is wrong and I am going to correct it. Thanks _again_. I could use an example of how to make this FP, but I guess this is off-topic...

Comment: In your question you mention that you're "just interested in learning Python and Java and welcome "drills" to practice on." This is a very small and simple example, what have you tried, where are you stuck?

Comment: @NominSim: should I provide my own port in Java and show the parts that I am unhappy with because they are verbose?

Comment: @Robottinosino That would be my suggestion, however I would leave out the Python part, and I would ask it on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead of [so]

Comment: I'm struggling to find your actual question here. And how do you define "compact"? Because anyone can code-golf the heck out of a program, doesn't mean it's a good thing.

Comment: Alright, so I need to add my Java port to provide context. One minute and I'll do that...

Comment: [btw, you could simplify the solution if you need only the number of ways to give change](http://ideone.com/C4hlk). It is both clear and "compact" — concise.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: nice hack, but I am on 2.7 and that assignment does not work. :( Thanks for sharing though! Can't wait to move to 3+!

Comment: to adapt it for 2.7 just use: `c, coins = coins[0], coins[1:]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really, almost everything you're doing here is directly convertible to Java, without much extra verbosity.

For example:

```
def make_change(money, coins):
  if money == 0 or len(coins) == 0: return 0
  return calculate_change(money, list(set(coins)), 0)
```

The obvious Java equivalent is:

```
public static int make_change(int money, int coins[]) {
  if (money == 0 || coins.length == 0) return 0;
  return calculate_change(money, coins, 0);
}
```

A few extra words here and there, an extra line because of the closing brace, and of course the explicit types… but beyond that, there's no big change.

Of course a more Python and Javariffic (what is the equivalent word?) version would be:

```
def make_change(money, coins):
  if money == 0 or len(coins) == 0: 
    return 0
  return calculate_change(money, list(set(coins)), 0)
```

The obvious Java equivalent is:

```
public static int make_change(int money, int coins[]) {
  if (money == 0 || coins.length == 0) {
    return 0;
  }
  return calculate_change(money, coins, 0);
}
```

So, Java gets one extra closing brace plus a few chars of whitespace; still not a big deal.

Putting the whole thing inside a class, and turning `main` into a method, adds about 3 more lines. Initializing an explicit array variable instead of using `[2, 1]` as a literal is 1 more. And `System.out.println` is a few characters longer than `print`, and `length` is 3 characters longer than `len`, and each comment takes two characters `//` instead of one `#`. But I doubt any of that is what you're worried about.

Ultimately, there's a total of one line that's tricky:

```
return (calculate_change(money, coins, total + c, combo + [c]) +
    calculate_change(money, coins[1:], total, combo))
```

A Java `int coins[]` doesn't have any way to say "give me a new array with the tail of the current one". The easiest solution is to pass an extra `start` parameter, so:

```
public static int calculate_change(int money, int coins[], int start, int total) {
    if (total == money) {
        return 1;
    }
    if (total > money || coins.length == start) {
        return 0;
    }
    return calculate_change(money, coins, 0, total + coins[start]) +
        calculate_change(money, coins, start + 1 total);
}
```

In fact, nearly everything can be trivially converted to C; you just need to pass yet another param for the length of the array, because you can't calculate it at runtime as in Java or Python.

The one line you're complaining about is an interesting point that's worth putting a bit more thought into. In Python, you've got (in effect):

```
comboWithC = combo + [c]
```

With Java's List, this is:

```
List<Integer> comboWithC = Lists.newArrayList(combo);
comboWithC.add(c);
```

This *is* more verbose. But that's intentional. Java `List<>` is not meant to be used this way. For small lists, copying everything around is no big deal, but for big lists, it can be a huge performance penalty. Python's `list` was designed around the assumption that most of the time, you're dealing with small lists, and copying them around is perfectly fine, so it should be trivial to write. Java's `List` was designed around the assumption that sometimes, you're dealing with huge lists, and copying them around is a very bad idea, so your code should make it clear that you really want to do that.

The ideal solution would be to either use an algorithm that didn't need to copy lists around, or to find a data structure that was designed to be copied that way. For example, in Lisp or Haskell, the default list type is perfect for this kind of algorithm, and there are about 69105 recipes for "Lisp-style lists in Java" or "Java cons" that you should be able to find online. (Of course you could also just write your a trivial wrapper around List that added an "addToCopy" method like Python's `__add__`, but that's probably not the right answer; you want to write idiomatic Java, or why use Java instead of one of the many other JVM languages?)

Comment: I should mention that this isn't meant to be an endorsement of Java, or proof that Java is compact. It's just that when you're doing something this simple, almost any language short of, say, assembler or Intercal can be simple and compact.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! How could I do this more concisely: List<Integer> comboWithC = Lists.newArrayList(combo); comboWithC.add(c);

Comment: Well, Java doesn't have a very compact way to write that equivalent to `comboWithC = combo + [c]`, but partly that's because Java's `List` is a different data structure than Python's `list`, and partly because Java is intentionally designed to make non-trivially-inefficient things like copying an entire list look non-trivial. But I don't understand where that line came from in translating your Python code to Java.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure I would. If you want to use immutable Lisp-style lists, `List<Integer>` is not a very good way to do it. Neither is Python's `list`, for that matter. But Python lets you do it anyway, because for very small lists there's no efficiency problem; Java refuses to help you out because for large lists there's a huge efficiency problem. You can force Java to do it anyway, with the code you wrote—it's intentionally not compact, to alert you to the fact that you're doing something possibly bad. Or you can google for "Lisp-style list in Java" or "cons Java" or something.

Comment: Thanks again for your input. It's strange there is no overload of List<T>, like "append", that returns the list itself so that one could pass myList.append(banana) to a method that accepts a List<T>. After all, both ArrayList and LinkedList could just grow... (now that is not passing a copy, though).